# Python script to parse commands from log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to write a Python script which would parse all commands within a log file.
After executing the script, it has to take the pasted log content as an input through stdin, then, output the result to stdout.

My issue is that my script is taking the argument after each command, while I need on each line the command without space. After trying to split at the end, I only get the first command.

I was looking a way to do it with regex, but I can't find a way to just display strings after keyword "COMMAND="

One line of the log file for example:

```
Jun 16 10:54:27 debian-srv sudo: linuxusr: TTY=pts/20 ; PWD=/home/linuxusr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
def main():
    auth_log_content = ''
    commands = []
    inp = input('auth log content: ')
    while inp != '':
        pattern = 'COMMAND='
        if pattern in inp:
            commands.append(inp.split(pattern)[-1].strip())
        inp = input('auth log content: ')


    print('==============FOUND COMMANDS==============')
    print('\n'.join(commands))

main()
```

Comment: Please always provide a [mre]. There is no need to have `input` calls in your code. Just hard-code your example input. Anyway, after putting your example in the code I get as output `/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log` which seems to be the expected output as it's the string after `COMMAND=`. If it is not, please [edit] your question and explain why

Comment: One line of the example was provided. Also I mentionned that I only need the first part after "COMMAND=", so in this example, I just want to display /usr/bin/tail

Comment: So you need to split that... `inp.split(pattern)[-1].split()[0]`... Or a regex would be better `COMMAND=(\S+)` and your result is in the first capture group...

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle input from stdin in a slightly different way to user interaction.

Something like this:

```
import re

commands = []

while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        if r := re.findall('COMMAND=(\S+)', line):
            commands.append(*r)
    except EOFError:
        break

print(commands)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have this error after running the code:
 ```File "auth3.py", line 8
    if r := re.findall('COMMAND=(\S+)', line):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: @n00bcoder That's because your Python version is **WAY** out of date. Current version is 3.10.5. The walrus operator (which is what's giving you a problem) was introduced in 3.8

Comment: thanks, trying to run on a Python 3.10.2 computer but it's only taking one line. Is there a way to take multiple pasted lines as input ?

Comment: @n00bcoder Yes. Paste all your lines into a file then redirect stdin to Python - e.g., *python yourscript.py < yourfile.log* or *cat yourfile.log | python yourscript.py*

Comment: On my windows terminal, trying but it's failing:
```type .\auth.log | python .\auth3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n00bcoder\Downloads\auth3.py", line 4, in <module>
    if r := re.findall('COMMAND=(\S+)', line):
NameError: name 're' is not defined```

I was more looking for a script that after executed, asks for input, then after pasting the lines, gives me only the commands. I don't know if you understand and if it is possible.

Comment: @n00bcoder You really need to concentrate. You failed to import *re*

Comment: Ohh, sorry, my bad, wrong copy-paste... I added a line break and put the commands in join to display each command on a single line.
```import re

commands = []

while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        if r := re.findall('COMMAND=(\S+)', line):
            commands.append(*r)
    except EOFError:
        break

print('\n'.join(commands))```

So there is no way to use stdin readlines to paste the content after the script execution ?